# I need to show on the screen FIRST object of the API: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

```
<body>
<h1>This is a page</h1>
<div id="page"></div>
<script>
    fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => {
           console.log(data)
           document.querySelector("#page").innerText = JSON.stringify(data)
       })
</script>

</body>
```

Here is my try, which shows all objects, but I need only the first one.

Comment: You just need to show people how your data looks like instead of all the codes. If that is a array, just get it by `array[0]`

Comment: ... and if it's not an array there is no such thing as the "first" one. properties don't have a guaranteed order.

Comment: There is only one object, do you mean first employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the API returns an object with `success` and `data` attributes, I'll consider you want the first `data` object so the first employee.

Look at [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on documentation, it's must-have knowledge in Javascript.

```html
<body>
  <h1>This is a page</h1>
  <div id="page"></div>
  <script>
    fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(data.data[0]);
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
<h1>This is a page</h1>
<div id="page"></div>
<script>
    fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => {
           console.log(data[0]) //notice the index in data
           document.querySelector("#page").innerText =JSON.stringify(data[0])
       })
</script>
```

That would be assuming the data is an array of objects, you could pick up the first element as you would in any array. Without seeing the response structure that would be the logical approach.

Comment: Data is an object, only one object, I don't understand the author too.

Comment: I tried this many time. The correct answer, which is working is above. data.data[0]

Comment: with other api this works actually, but it didn't work in my case where I asked the question